# Add pagination in a Wordpress Latest Posts widget

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

In a Wordpress Latest Posts widget I want to add pagination

```html
 public function widget($args, $instance) {
  extract($args);
  $title    = apply_filters('widget_title', $instance['title'] );
  $count    = $instance['count'];
  $category   = $instance['category'];
  echo $before_widget;
  $output = '';
  if ( $title )
   echo $before_title . $title . $after_title;
  global $post;
  if ( isset( $category ) && $category != '' ) {
   $args = array(
    'category_name'  => $category,
    'posts_per_page' => $count,
   );
  } else {
   $args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => $count,
   );
  }
  $posts = get_posts( $args );
  if(count($posts)>0){
   $output .='<div class="sp-latest-posts-widget latest-posts">';
   foreach ($posts as $post): setup_postdata($post);
    $output .='<div class="media">';

     if(has_post_thumbnail()):
      $output .='<div class="pull-left">';
      $output .='<a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'xs-thumb', array('class' => 'img-responsive')).'</a>';
      $output .='</div>';
     endif;

     $output .='<div class="media-body">';
     $output .= '<h3 class="entry-title"><a href="'.get_permalink().'">'. get_the_title() .'</a></h3>';
     $output .= '<div class="entry-meta small"><span class="st-lp-time">'. get_the_time() . '</span> <span clss="st-lp-date">' . get_the_date('d M Y') . '</span></div>';
     $output .='</div>';
    $output .='</div>';
   endforeach;
   wp_reset_query();
   $output .='</div>';
  }
  echo $output;
  echo $after_widget;
 }
```

I tried with pagination_nav(); after adding code in functions.php and I used WP-PageNavi, but without success. 
How to add numbered pagination in this case?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Use below code for numbered pagination,

```
<?php the_posts_pagination( array(
      'mid_size'  => 1,
      'prev_text' => __( 'Prev', 'textdomain' ),
      'next_text' => __( 'Next', 'textdomain' ),
      'screen_reader_text' => ' ',
    ) );

     } ?>
```

Comment: Thank you baiju jha for your answer but my issue is that I can not display pagination, either with numbers or others.